# Inferior statement

Tags: excel, if-statement

Hi I have the following formula with date fields. If AP2 is blank how do I add an error message to my formula please?

`=IF(P2-AP2<365,"Death<1 year",Death >=one year")`

I have tried adding iferror and'"Date missing")

Comment: Note that your logic doesn't handle leap years.

Comment: Use the `IsBlank()` function.

Comment: Can you help with the formula please

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"Date Missing",IF((B1-A1)<365,"Death<1 year","Death >= one year"))`

Comment: Thank you and I apologise for the delay in getting back to you.

Comment: Thanks! Please mark this post as solved if this answers your question.